# Developing a plausible monster in the Canadian wilderness

Tags: biology, creature-design

## Premise

I need help designing the behaviour/hunting patters of a beastie that lives in the Canadian wilderness to terrorize our protagonists.

## Information

The area this creature would live in would consist of densely wooded coniferous forests. Creature would be an ambush predator.

The creature is relatively large/tall when compared to a human, has head-pulpifying strength, uses sound to hunt and is cunning enough to create and lure prey into traps. Has a monstrous worm like head (regardless of biological plausibility)

## Question

Based on the aforementioned information, what would this creature actually hunt like? How does it avoid having its monstrous bulk scare off prey items?

Comment: It sounds like you already know what you want it to look like. What further details is it that you need?

Comment: It would look like a beast that is taller than a human and has a toothed-worm like head.

Comment: Sounds like [Drop Bears](https://australianmuseum.net.au/drop-bear), though they're Australian native.

Comment: Having grown up in Alberta, the Canadian forests, apart from BC, are thickly treed, but the trees tend to be too spindly to be climbable. Once you get north of Edmonton, it's pretty much all muskeg with stands of short evergreens until you hit tundra.

Comment: Adding to pojo-guy's comment, if I saw a big creature like this hanging onto the top of a pine tree, I'd simply turn around and quickly walk away as it impaled itself on the branches of the pine tree trying to jump down. Unless it's in BC, the trees wouldn't support it or are so thickly branched jumping from them is a good way to get killed. A predator that could hide under the branches of pine trees and in the thick bushes of the boreal forest (the most common forest in Canada) watching silently as I saunter along a path is far more likely, and terrifying to me as an average hunter.

Comment: Having grown up in New Brunswick and spent years in forests across Canada, second pojo-guy. The boreal forest isn't set up for a large ambush predator dropping down. Think about the stereotypical conifer, ie a Christmas tree. Wider at the bottom. Something large trying to jump down from an upper branch is going to run smack into a tangle of limbs on the way down.

Comment: @pojo-guy Yeah, I realized that but I wondered if there was any way for such a creature to actually climb said trees and be an effective hunter.

Comment: @TimB I was wondering about more specific details, like whether this creature would be a hulking beast or a needle like predator. What adaptions it would need for its kind of hunting, how it would blend in, etc.

Comment: Grizzlies are darned smart, super-strong, scary as a nightmare...and already native to the area. Not scary enough? Fine: Two Grizzlies. Make one an angry mom. II'll be in the next county.

Comment: Does it play hockey?

Comment: The two traits of bigger than a man yet still small enough to drop from trees in the Canadian north aren't easy to reconcile (been in northern Alberta and BC, trees that can support a larger than human climber aren't frequent).  A Giant short-faced bear (extinct now) would hit the size and scary components quickly (14 feet tall on average and the face of teeth for that matter), or the wolverine for the climbing/vicious/take on anything component.  Hard to get one creature to satisfy both.

Comment: A second question...I'm unsure on what your visioned Canadian forest looks like.  We actually get weather patterns that prevent larger trees from prevailing, such as a spring snow storm.  In spring when the trees are budding, we can get a snowstorm caused by a northern arctic front getting pushed south, sometimes far into the US.  This front interacts with the warmer/humid air and produces giant sticky snowflakes that create enough weight to tear down branches from larger trees...any tree with limbs capable of supporting your beast climbing it would get torn down and therefore don't exist.

Comment: @Twelfth: And that's assuming the mature trees (in southern parts) haven't all been logged off and replaced with spindly 2nd and 3rd growth :-(

Comment: you need to define what you mean by "plausible" and what you actually want from us, becasue as it stands it seems like you already have your answer.

Comment: @Separatrix Australians are invereate international travellers. It's just Drop Bears with Canadian visas. Nice to see a non-Aussie showing awareness of our most infamous predator.

Comment: @Twelfth I was picturing Banff-like Coniferous forests, but I've quickly realized there is absolutely no plausible way a large creature could actually hunt in this manner. Have modified question to actually make sense.

Comment: @a4android, it's important to know the risks in areas to which you might travel. Few outside Scotland know the risks of meeting a wild haggis on a dark hillside and how to escape the encounter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1. The Wendigo

This white-furred bestial man-eating creature seems to perfectly fit your request. It lurks in the wintry wind, stealthy despite its large size, and is insatiably hungry. This supernatural beast is sourced from Algonquin legends, a native American tribe that lived around the Great Lakes.

Two easy sources for further information are [Until Dawn](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Wendigo_(Until_Dawn)) (the 2015 computer game), which showcases a weaker, more humanoid version of the creature, and [Descent: Journeys in the Dark](http://descent2e.wikia.com/wiki/Wendigo) (the 2016 board game), which has the toothed worm-like head you're looking for, as below:

[image]

### 2. The Sasquatch

This large, hairy, bipedal ape-like being reportedly lives in the Pacific Northwest (esp. Washington state and British Columbia) and stands roughly 6-9 feet tall. Various native American legends have variants of this creature, some are notedly gentle, others are ferocious and capable of carrying off humans to be eaten.

No versions of this legendary critter have a worm-like head with teeth, but there's no reason why a mutant version can't exist.

Comment: Bigfoot + Tremors = Nightmares

Comment: I had no idea there was a version of the wendigo with a worm-like head. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd also recommend Algernon Blackwood's short story The Wendigo as a good example. This particular one fits very well with the creature description given by OP.

Answer (score 6):

So large, strong, quite clever, carnivorous, lives in the canadian wilderness.

A bear?

Maybe one that got hurt and disfigured  in a forest fire and now hunts humans because they are the only creatures slow enough chase down.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to make it up.  Wolverines are very close.

Fishers are mustellids, in the weasel family. They are arboreal predators but too small for your needs.

[image: fisher in tree]

But wolverines are mustellids too.  They live in the north.  They can also be arboreal.

[image: wolverine in tree]

Wolverines are formidable predators.  They are as strong, smart, relentless and fierce in the weasel way - they kill for pleasure.  Wolverines can take elk and moose.  A wolverine is outmatched by a bear and probably could not catch one by surprise by dropping onto it - unless the wolverine were smart enough to disguise its scent by rolling in the carrion it knows will attract the bear.

The dead grizzly can be an opening scene, like when they find the dead orca at the beginning of Jaws.  The dead bear by the carrion, the side of its head torn off, its body uneaten.

Scale up the wolverine - a mutant that is 50% bigger and 50% smarter.  You are all set.

Comment: A wolverine that size would be terrifying. But it climbs trees to hide its kill, safety and to see around the area. Not to hunt from. Otherwise good answer, I'd be more terrified of it than a Sasquatch.

Answer (score 0):

The Canadian wilderness contains several types of (rarely) man-eating or man killing monsters.

1) Polar bears.  the largest carnivores on land and quite willing to eat humans.

2) Grizzly bears.

3) Black bears.

4) Cougars or mountain lions.

5) Wolves.

6) Coyotes.  There is one case where Canadian coyotes killed an adult human.

7) wolverines.  They can attack and kill humans but rarely do so.

Both mountain lions and wolverines are said to sometimes jump out of trees onto their prey.

So if you want to make your monster a hard science fiction monster instead of a fantasy or horror monster you should take one of those and make it much bigger, stronger and more dangerous and also make it much more likely to attack.  Climate change or something has killed all its prey and it is starving, it has rabies, a human killed her babies, or like "Big Ghost Basin" it was burned in a fire and ferociously attacks campfires and those who make them, etc.